# How to select a platform from the command line in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm messing around with Bazel example files. This one in particular on [github](https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/main/rules/actions_run/BUILD), seems to select a tool by checking which platform is detected (specified?). If I execute:

```
bazel build :sh
```

it uses Linux. I deleted the default rule, and it still picked up Linux, so it looks like it autodetects the platform.

However, I'd like to know how to force it to use windows/something else. I know bazel has a `--platforms` command line argument, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pick the windows one. So, is it possible and if so, how do you select it?

Answer (score 2):

Bazel effectively defaults to the target, host, and exec platforms all matching the local build system. There's some additional indirection to support migrating from older ways of specifying the platforms (`--cpu`, `--crosstool_cop`, etc), but that is being moved away from so I would not start with that system for a new project. [Building with Platforms](https://bazel.build/concepts/platforms-intro) talks more about the migration.

If you have a platform and a toolchain for your desired target platform, you should be able to build by just passing `--incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution --platforms=//my:platform`. The [Status section](https://bazel.build/concepts/platforms-intro#status) of that docs page lists flags for other languages.

You'll have to find a toolchain and find/write a platform for your target. The [Configure C++ Toolchains](https://bazel.build/tutorials/cc-toolchain-config) tutorial walks through creating a toolchain. Writing a platform is pretty simple, something like this:

```py
platform(
    name = "linux_armv7",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:armv7",
    ],
)
```

Comment: I'd generally put `build --incompatible_enable_cc_toolchain_resolution` into the `.bazelrc` in order to disable the legacy behaviour, so you don't accidentally rely on it in new projects.