# how to Use --platform detail from command line command inside bazel rules as a variable/argument

Tags: bazel

Is there any way to get details of platform from --platform=//platform:stm32f405ig command line command? In short I want to have device type argument to be passed to my python program and I want to get that information automatically by looking at --platform. Ex: Device type= stm32f405ig for bazel build //target --platform=//platform:stm32f405ig

Comment: Found this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225473/how-to-select-a-platform-from-the-command-line-in-bazel).

Comment: @SG_Bazel Thank you for responding. The solution for this is to use ctx.target_platform_has_constraint.